# outputting CSV file to HTML talbe with PHP - how to replace a word with an image?

Tags: php, csv, replace

Sorry I have searched high and low for an answer and I am stumped. Essentially what I want to do is replace a certain word with an image.

I have a CSV file and I am outputting the data into an HTML table using PHP code. Is there a way I can have the php find all the instances of the word "smile!" and replace it with something like this

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/smile.jpg" />
```

So that way the HTML will output the graphic and not the word "smile!"?

Also a second thought, I don't know if I can have the PHP switch it to something like the template_directory... maybe it would be easier to switch it to "http://website.com/images/smile.jpg"?

ok here using the anonymous suggestion I wrote this as my full code, but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
$path_to_file = "http://....conquer.csv";
$smile = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$smile = str_replace("smile!","<img src=\"http://.........../images/smile.png\" />",$smile);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$smile);

echo "<table id=\"conquer-table\">\n";

$row = 0;
$handle = fopen("http://.........oad/conquer.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  if ($row == 0) {
    // this is the first line of the csv file
    // it usually contains titles of columns
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<thead>\n<tr>";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo "<th>" . $data[$c] . "</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n</thead>\n\n<tbody>";
} else {
    // this handles the rest of the lines of the csv file
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<tr>";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo "<td>" . $data[$c] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
   }
  }

 fclose($handle);

 echo "</tbody>\n</table>";

 ?>
```

Comment: Sorry I forget to add block code, thanks for the very quick negative rating! lol

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with `str_replace`:

```
$string = /*FULL TEXT HERE*/;
$string = str_replace('smile!','<img src="<?php bloginfo(\'template_directory\'); ?>/images/smile.jpg" />',$string);
```

For it to replace it with a different text, just replace `<img src="<?php bloginfo(\'template_directory\'); ?>/images/smile.jpg" />` with something else, and `smile!` represents what the code is looking for.

Comment: @randyttp Here is an example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cin-zzt  Press Run to see the result.  If it is still not working, you would need to be more specific as to what is not working.

Comment: That didn't work for me yet, I did update my original question with my full code so maybe you can see better what I am trying to achieve... The CSV file is going to have the words that I need replaced.

Comment: In that case, you could set `$string` equal to `file_get_contents('http://.........oad/conquer.csv')` and the code will replace the occurrences of `smile!` that it finds in that file with the new text and set that as the new `$string` variable.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies! Still can't get it to work while messing around with the file_get_contents. I'm sure I must be doing something wrong. PHP newbie

Comment: No problem.  Try echoing `htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('http://.........oad/conquer.csv'))` and see if you are checking the right file.

Comment: Its the right file. It is already outputting fine and correctly to the HTML table... However the word "smile!" is staying the same and is not being replaced.

Comment: I do not see any reason why it would not work.  Could you please update the code in the question so that I could see if there is possibly an error with how it fetches the data?

Comment: Ok I see the problem.  You can't use the `http://` wrapper for `file_put_contents` even if it is the same domain.  This is to prevent users from having the ability to change any webpage.  For `file_put_contents` (and `file_get_contents` depending on the file type) it is better to use the shortened link.  For example: `file_put_contents('images/smile.png',$smile)`.